# How would I say to someone, "be yourself"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

If I wanted to advise or counsel someone that they should be themselves because this would ultimately make them happy, how would I say this?

My initial thought is something like:

> Te Ipsum Es

Is there something like this already that is attested, or possibly more idiomatic? It does not need to include the reason why you should be yourself; I only want the imperative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Gerere se aliquo modo* is an idiomatic expression that [according to L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dgero1) means: "to bear, deport, behave, or conduct one's self, to act in any manner". I think this makes very good option for what we are seeking, since the imperative "Be" here is really in the sense of "act as".

*aliquo modo* might be replaced with ablative (as in the formula), but also with an adverb ("turpissimē"), but even with simple adj. ("se medium gerere" - to remain neutral, Liv. 2, 27, 3.). So we might think of some different options here:

- **Gere te liberē** (*liberē* - an adverb that means freely/unrestrained)
- **Gere te naturalem/naturaliter** (*naturalem* - adjective here; naturaliter - adv.)

Eventually, however, had I to chose one, I could not have resisted of using a quite cool word that I have recently learned (The hearer of which is likely to never forget it):

**tuātim** (=in your way/ *tuo more*) [we also have *meātim*]. It produces:

> **Gere te tuatim**.

I like the repeat of *tu* here, I think it adds to the message. But as *tuatim* is very rare word, one might be inclined to replace it with *tuo more*:

- **Gere te tuo more**